# How do I join the next line when a line matches a regex for whole document in VI?

Tags: vim, regular-expression

I have lines like

```
abcdefg
join!
abcdef
no join
abcdefg
join!
```

If a line matches regex `^a.+g$` then I would like them to be joined, so it would be:

```
abcdefgjoin!
abcdef
no join
abcdefgjoin!
```

Is there a way of doing that in `VIM`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In normal mode, `J` (as distinct from `j`, which moves the cursor down one line) is used to join a line with the one directly beneath it. However, by default it adds a space to the end of the first line; to get the result you want (joining the lines without inserting an additional space), one would have to use `gJ`.

In order to use normal-mode commands in ex-mode (which you enter by pressing `:` while in normal mode), one must use the `normal` command. See `:h normal` within vim. So, to work with the next line that matches the pattern, one would use (note that by default, you have to escape the `+` to get it to work with vim's regex, a consequence of maintaining compatibility with the original vi's ancient regex engine):

```
:/^a.\+g$/normal gJ
```

To work on *every* line that matches the pattern, one would use the `:global` command (see `:h :g` within vim) like so:

```
:global/^a.\+g$/normal gJ
```

Or, more concisely:

```
:g/^a.\+g$/norm gJ
```

It's also possible to use the ex command `join` (see `:h :join`) to achieve the same thing with very slightly less typing (the `!` at the end, in this case, tells `join` not to insert a space at the end of the first line).

```
:g/^a.\+g$/join!
```

Comment: thanks for the ex command. in _wasavi_, the `normal` command does not work, but `join` does.

Comment: Neither of these seem to work for joining consecutive lines. If I have *n* lines in a row matching the pattern, I have to repeat the command roughly *n/2* times...

Answer (score 2):

A "pure" regex solution would be

```
:%s/^\(a.\+g\)\n/\1/
```

The advantage it has is that you can use it to extract a desirable string from the target line and combine it with the following line; for instance to trim off trailing whitespace

```
:%s/^(a.\+g\)[ \t]\+\n/\1/
```